# Several ng-click on button angular?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have one button that have ng-click, like this

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right push-right-5" role="button" ng-click="model.assignToProjects()">GO</button>
```

What i need is to add new action to ng-click, like this

```
ng-click="submitted=true"
```

The problem is i have application that is to big and i need to have some common event that will do first event, if it is valid allow second event, that can be anything :( Here how my HTML should look like

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right push-right-5" role="button" ng-click="submitted=true ; model.assignToProjects();">GO</button>
```

Is it possible to do this way or i must rewrite my entire logic :(

Comment: First of all you have to validate form before calling a submit function.

Comment: Yes but i need to show error messages when button is clicked , but now click go bypass validation

Comment: in a validation function you have to return true or false. if it return false then populate error before calling submit function.

Comment: You can see there is no submit just ng-click, and i dont know what function can be on ng-click, except i need to add validation before that function

Comment: In controller write a function name $scope.submit = function () { var validate = true if(validate=true) then perform action else show error}

Comment: Yes but i have so many contollers, i need logic for just HTML and maybe directive, not rewriting all controllers

Comment: please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602565/angular-js-ng-click-validation

Comment: You are again telling me to chnage to submit, mate i dont want that i need to stay ng-click

Comment: you can pass a param to assignToProject. chaining instruction in ngclick should work too but it's ugly

Comment: Can you write simple solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855082/angularjs-validation-on-submit-only

Comment: Rashid is still dont know what are you trying to do??? Mate i dont have submit i only have ng-click???